# Prove that the conditional probability $P_B(A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ is a probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> $$\text{Prove that the conditional probability } P_B(A)=\frac{P(A\cap
> B)}{P(B)} \text{ is a probability.}$$

I wasn't sure what I need to show, so I checked that in abook and it's saying that something is a probability if these three axioms are satisfied:

1. $\forall \text{ A} \in \epsilon$ we have that $0\leq P(A)\leq1$
2. $P(\Omega)=1$
3. $P(\bigcup _{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(A_i)$

So if this is the correct approach I already have troubles at showing 1. :s

I tried:

$P(B)=P(A \cap B)+P(B \setminus A) \Leftrightarrow P(A \cap B) = P(B)-P(B \setminus A)$

We already see that $P(A \cap B) \geq 0$ and $P(B) \geq 0$ and $P(A \cap B) \geq P(B)$, thus the fraction will be $\geq 0$

But I don't know how could 2. be shown and especially 3.? Did I do 1. correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's right, you need to show that $P_{B}$ satisfies the three axioms.

1. Since $P(A\cap B), P(B) \geqslant 0$, we get $P_B(A) \geqslant 0$ and $P_B(A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B \setminus A)+P(A\cap B)}\leqslant 1$

   $P_{B}(\Omega) = \frac{P(\Omega \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(B)}{P(B)} = 1$

   Let $A_{1},A_{2},...$ be pairwise disjoint events. Then using that $P$ is a probability we get

\begin{align}
\quad P_{B}(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i}) = \frac{P((\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i}) \bigcap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(A_{i} \cap B))}{P(B)} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(A_{i} \cap B)}{P(B)} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P_{B}(A_{i})
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry for necroposting. For point 3, I think that $A_1, A_2, ... $ should be $ \textbf{disjoint} $ events rather than $ \textbf{independent} $ events.

Comment: Do we not also need to include $P_B(\emptyset) = 0$. A possible proof is... $P(\emptyset) = 0$ and given we divide by $P(B)$, $B ≠ \emptyset$ indeed as a part of this, given that we divide by B, do we technically need to assume $P(B) > 0$ this is what my professor does!